# How to Render FACEBOOK like button for each one of my records jsf java

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.fbComponent}" />
```

col fbComponent (VARCHAR) & Getter and Setter in Class Bean for required component
The problem is that records in the db are being stored between (quotes?)'....'. Is there a way to store addresses or this kind of code on mysql rather than using '....'?

```
@Column(name = "fbComponent")
private String fbComponent;

//delete first and last char (')
public String getFBComponent() {
    StringBuilder fb = new StringBuilder(fbComponent);
    fb.deleteCharAt(0);
    fb.deleteCharAt(fb.length()-1);
    return fb.toString();
}
//delete first and last char (')
public void setFBComponent(String fbComponent) {
    StringBuilder fb = new StringBuilder(fbComponent);
    fb.deleteCharAt(0);
    fb.deleteCharAt(fb.length()-1);
    this.fbComponent = fb.toString();
}
```

Output:

```
&lt;fb:like href=&quot;http://www.faceb......and goes on
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h:outputText` escapes text by default. That means the `escape` flag is indicating that characters that are sensitive in HTML and XML markup must be escaped. This flag is set to `true` by default.

If I understood your question correctly, you only need to set `escape` to `false`.

Try:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.fbComponent}" escape="false"/>
```

Comment: @Ignacio: You are welcome. I added a short explanation to my answer.